# How to highlight Outlook contacts

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin

Is there a way how to display some contacts from Outlook's contact list in different manner?

So far I've seen, that there is quite some customization available for Office applications, however I haven't seen anything even remotely close to this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to display Outlook contacts in a different color.

Comment: Ok. And what about displaying them in different manner? Different font, color, whatever  - will work for us ... Is this possible somehow?

Comment: You can use conditional formatting in the list view only - click View | View Settings | Conditional Formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, indeed this is what I found - it is possible only via adding of the new AutoFormatRule to the Outlook.TableView.

Sample code would be something like:

```
Outlook.AutoFormatRule autoFormatRule = tableView.AutoFormatRules.Add("My own rule");
autoFormatRule.Font.Bold = true;
autoFormatRule.Font.Strikethrough = true;
autoFormatRule.Filter = <filtering>;

tableView.Save();
tableView.Apply();
```

For filling in 'filtering' part one can use [DASL Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx)
But I still need to figure out what to do with the non-list views.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest only one possible way - replace the default folder view with a custom form where you can display entries in the way you need. See [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a) for more information.

Also you may consider using Add-in Express. They provide such layouts out of the box. See [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php).

Note, you can use any .net controls on top of custom forms.

Comment: No, Add-In Express is exactly what I didn't want to use. Our add-in is very simple thing, almost no UI, with one or two things we need to solve - so far no reason to pay for some external products.

Comment: It is up to you which way is to choose.